# How to debug a flash program on target ARM MCU with gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, gdbserver, segger-jlink

I am trying to debug a ARM flash program on target MCU using `gdb`

I am setting up the gdbserver on target system (cortex-m7) with `jlinkgdbserver`. And I have a elf ready for debug.

For the first time, it is OK for me do debug with the following

```
> arm-none-eabi-gdb flash_program.elf
(gdb)> target remote localhost:2331     # connect to gdb server on target
(gdb)> load                             # since it is a flash program, jlink will flash the program
                                        # target is reset to elf entry point
(gdb)> .... (debugging begins)
```

However, when debug goes to some place, and I want to debug from the entry point again, the way I figured out is do flashing again

```
(gdb)> Ctrl+D               # disconnect the gdbserver
> arm-none-eabi-gdb flash_program.elf
(gdb)> target remote localhost:2331
(gdb)> load
(gdb)> .... (debugging from start again)
```

So this seems a bit redundant, also it erase and program the same flash area again and again, I am afraid I will end up damaging the storage through my debugging.

The flash program has already been burned into the medium, I simply want to let the target to reset itself and run from entry point again. But I tried things like `monitor reset` and `run`. But the target M7 both can't start from beginning again.

Is there any other gdb command that I can try?

Comment: What are the brand/model of the Cortex-M7 you are using ? this would help providing you  with a precise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an `STM32F103C8T6` for providing an answer, but you will just have to replace its ROM base address (`0x20000000`) by the one your Cortex-M7 uses: In my case, I loaded the initial value for the stack pointer from `0x20000000`, and the initial value for the program counter from `0x20000000+4`.

The program to be debugged was `stm32f103c8t6.elf`, was already flashed and did contain the debug symbols.

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb

target remote localhost:2331
0x20000480 in ?? ()
(gdb) monitor halt
(gdb) monitor reset 0
Resets core & peripherals via SYSRESETREQ & VECTRESET bit.
(gdb) monitor reset 1
Resets the core only, not peripherals.
(gdb) monitor reset 2
Resets core & peripherals using RESET pin.
(gdb) symbol-file stm32f103c8t6.elf
Reading symbols from stm32f103c8t6.elf...
(gdb) set $sp = *0x20000000
(gdb) set $pc = *0x20000004
(gdb) stepi
0x200003c2      121     {
(gdb)
0x200003c4      121     {
(gdb) stepi
122       SystemInit();                             /* CMSIS System Initialization */
(gdb)
SystemInit () at /opt/arm/ARM.CMSIS.5.6.0//Device/ARM/ARMCM3/Source/system_ARMCM3.c:61
61      {
(gdb)
```

Depending on the type of reset strategy you want to use, you may have to explicit it in the `monitor reset` command:

As explained in the Segger documentation and [this great article](https://dzone.com/articles/hardware-reset-for-arm-cortex-m-with-segger-j-link), you can use strategy number 0, 1 or 2:

```
# Normal
monitor reset
monitor reset 0

# Core
monitor reset 1

# ResetPin
monitor reset 2
```

My understanding is that being able to use strategy #2 depends on how your RESET pin was wired, i.e. if it is pulled-down or not on your board.

**Disclaimer**: I am a software person, and all interpretation errors related to hardware-related questions are mine...

Comment: @Eric Sun: Is the answer clear enough, or does it need to be improved ? thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I understand that you are retrieving initial SP and PC from ROM start and let the code running from start again. But this is different from a `HARD RESET`, which reinitialize all the register and SOC modules. I am thinking whether there is some built-in JTAG reset command that can achieve that.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest to modify your question and augment  `But the target M7 both can't start from beginning again.` with the 'hard reset' considerations you exposed in your comment. You may be able to achieve your goal by issuing a 'type 2' reset, as explained in  [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/hardware-reset-for-arm-cortex-m-with-segger-j-link), and of course the corresponding section of the JLink documentation, depending on how your reset signal is wired.

Comment: I augmented my answer accordingly, I think it should now answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

gdb command **load** will flash the image, provided that you have not setup the link address specially.
You have two option to survive:

1. setup the link address / adjust the linker script, so the program will be totally in RAM. Or
2. Keep the address not changed, but each time after code change & compile, use **load** once only (to make the flash being programmed), then later use **symbol-file** command to load only symbol.